# Shiny: problem with encoding/special characters when launching app through batch-file

Tags: r, batch-file, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm writing a small batch-script to launch a shinydashboard-app, so people who are not familiar with R can easily access the app. Everything is working so far, except that special characters (namely ä, ö and ü) are not displayed correctly when I'm launching the app through the batch-script. All the R-Files are saved with UTF-8 encoding. Maybe there's an option in the .bat-file that I am missing? I already added to Sys.setlocale()-command to the R-file but that did not solve the problem. I've constructed a small example to illustrate the problem:

---

**apptest.R**

```
library(shiny)

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "German")

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel with ä"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("sidebar panel with ü"),
    mainPanel("main panel with ö")
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(port = 7924))
```

---

**runAppTest.bat**

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\Rscript.exe" apptest.R
SLEEP 5
start "" http://127.0.0.1:7924
```

---

you might need to adjust C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\Rscript.exe for your version or just put 'Rscript.exe' there if you've added it to your PATH.

If you launch the app through R-Studio you'll see that the letters are displayed correctly. If you do it through the .bat-file it looks like this:

[image]

That looks like an encoding problem to me, but I haven'T been able to solve it. CVan anybody help me in this matter? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried tho play around with the [`chcp` command](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) in the batch file (using cope pages `437`, `650`, `1252`, `65001`)? (although I do not have too much hope with this, because the `.R` files are not read by the batch script, so it appears kind of illogical to me)

Comment: Also you should change console font to a truetype font.

Comment: does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could suggest a workaround I used when i had a similar problem.

Use a wrapper file to ensure the encoding (here: callAppEncoded.R).

**Script order would be:**

CMD / .bat **-->** 
callAppEncoded.R  `source("<PATHTO>/app.R", encoding = "UTF-8")` **-->**
app.R

**Reproducible example (tested):**

**CMD / .bat**

```
Rscript.exe  <PATHTO>/callAppEncoded.R
```

**callAppEncoded.R**

```
source("<PATHTO>/app.R", encoding = "UTF-8", echo = TRUE)
```

Edit: As suggested by OP adding `echo = TRUE`. For me it was optional for OP required.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "German")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel with ä"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("sidebar panel with ü"),
    mainPanel("main panel with ö")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

runApp(
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(port = 7924))  
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I added `echo = TRUE` to the source-command, otherwise it wouldn't work.